# How to stream several large files to jetty

Tags: java, rest, streaming, jetty, multipartform-data

I would like to send several large files via HTTP using multipart/formdata.

I actually just want to stream them through my service, so I'd like to get the different parts as streams and absolutely would like to avoid that the whole request is buffered in memory before I get a chance to pass the data on.

I get the feeling that with jetty (we're using Dropwizard 0.7.1 which comes with jetty 9.0.7) the whole request gets buffered before my code is executed.

Is there a way to avoid that? Ideally, I'd like to have an event-based system (which fires an event like "next part with name xxx" and gives me a stream I can consume).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request with `multipart/formdata` is processed by various internal components to break apart the sections so that [`HttpServletRequest.getParts()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts()) (and various similar methods) can work properly.

**Option #1: Handle Multi-part yourself**

It can be a bit tricky to subvert this behavior of the Servlet spec, but I'll give it a go.

First, do *not* declare the [`@MultipartConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html) configuration for the servlet you want to handle this request data.

Next, do *not* access methods in the `HttpServletRequest` that need to know about the parameters of the request, or its parts.

Override the [`HttpServlet.service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)) method, not the `doPost()` method, and process the raw Request payload content yourself.

This means you'll be writing a MultiPart InputStream Parser, and handling the parsing of the multi-part yourself.  There's plenty of examples of this online, you'll just want to pick one that makes more sense to you.

**Option #2: Don't use POST with multi-part**

If you are streaming upload a file, don't use POST with multi-part, use PUT with raw payload data, then you'll skip the entire layer of magic that is the multi-part request POST payload.

Comment: you could try streaming the file via websockets too.  If the files are truely large, you'll want retry/continue logic anyway.